# Grouping by an attribute in xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-grouping

Hi i am a little stuck with this problem my xml is as

```
<album>
     <title>album name</title>    
     <tracks>
           <track tracksequence="1" disksequence="1">track 1 - disc 1</track>
           <track tracksequence="2" disksequence="1">track 2 - disc 1</track>
           <track tracksequence="3" disksequence="1">track 3 - disc 1</track>
           <track tracksequence="1" disksequence="2">track 1 - disc 2</track>
           <track tracksequence="2" disksequence="2">track 2 - disc 2</track>
           <track tracksequence="3" disksequence="2">track 3 - disc 2</track>
           <track tracksequence="4" disksequence="2">track 4 - disc 2</track>
           <track tracksequence="1" disksequence="3">track 1 - disc 3</track>
           <track tracksequence="2" disksequence="3">track 2 - disc 3</track>
     </tracks>
</album>
```

i would like to be able to output as

```
<div>
<span>album name disc 1</span>
track 1 disc 1
track 2 disc 1
track 3 disc 1
</div>

<div>
<span>album name disc 2</span>
track 1 disc 2
track 2 disc 2
track 3 disc 2
track 4 disc 2 
</div>

ect...
```

im sure that i need to use some sort of Muenchian grouping but im having difficulty getting my head around it for my particular usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="sortByDisk" match="track" use="@disksequence"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tracks/track[
            count(. | key('sortByDisk', @disksequence)[1]) = 1
        ]"/>
    </body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="track">
    <div>
        <span>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../title"/>
            <xsl:text> disc</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@disksequence"/>
        </span>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('sortByDisk', @disksequence)"
            mode="inner"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="track" mode="inner">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output (using your sample):

```
<body>
    <div>
        <span>album name disc1</span>
        <p>track 1 - disc 1</p>
        <p>track 2 - disc 1</p>
        <p>track 3 - disc 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>album name disc2</span>
        <p>track 1 - disc 2</p>
        <p>track 2 - disc 2</p>
        <p>track 3 - disc 2</p>
        <p>track 4 - disc 2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>album name disc3</span>
        <p>track 1 - disc 3</p>
        <p>track 2 - disc 3</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks alot for that Flack, although in my live example my template isnt applying to my track, ie in your example the track mode="inner" not sure why this is, although it is outputting all the data from the node. /head scratch!

Comment: @Treemonkey, have you managed to implement the solution? I have no problem to add edits, if you post your current code.

Comment: thanks, i think its probably something fairly simple causing it to break. the problem above is very simplified! will update soon just having a cuppa and making sure i've got everything correct!

Comment: ahh lol, yep was my error i failed to update a reference to seperate xslt file which requires mode adding! school boy error :P